# How can I copy a URL from an image's src attribute to an href attribute in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my HTML code

```
<div class="anythingWindow">
    <ul class="anythingSlider">
      <li class="panel activePage">
        <div class="content clearfix" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
          <a href="http://www.example.com/a.jpg" class="focusedLink">
            <img src= "http://www.example.com/a.jpg"/>
          </a>
          <div class="slider-text">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit
            <a title="" href="#">Read More</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="panel activePage">
        <div class="content clearfix" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
          <a href="http://www.example.com/a.jpg" class="focusedLink">
            <img src= "http://www.example.com/a.jpg"/>
          </a>
          <div class="slider-text">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit
            <a title="" href="#">Read More</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

As you can see in `div.content > a > img` there is image with specific location. How can I copy the URL from this image to the `href` attribute of `div.slider-text > a`?

I tried jQuery's `each()` method, but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: `div.content > img > a` points to nothing. You mean `div.content > a > img` right ?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: This question is missing [sample code](http://sscce.org/) that shows what you've tried, as well as a description of what it actually does (as opposed to what you want it to do).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this;

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.anythingSlider .panel').each(function() {
     var $this = $(this);

     // Get src attribute from img
     var url = $this.find('.content a img').first().attr('src');

     // Set href attribute on a
     $this.find('.content .slider-text a').first().attr('href', url);

  });

});
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe this is what you want:

```
$(".anythingSlider img").each(function(){
    var src = $(this).src();
    $(this).parent("a").next(".slider-text").children("a").attr("href", src);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is incorrect. The `<a>` element is the direct child of `div.content`, not the `<img>` element, and then the `<img>` element is the direct child of the `<a>` element. Try using `div.content > a > img` instead.