# Using JavaScript to copy image URL to Schema Microdata

Tags: javascript, schema.org, microdata

I have a page with several images where I want to add Microdata. My HTML is structured in the following way:

```html
<article class="photo">
  <div class="post__content">
    <a href="http://example.com/page">
      <img class="post__img" src="http://example.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>
</article>
```

The url for the image is generated dynamically, so I would like to create a script that copies the URL and adds it under the corresponding schema entry:

```json
{
  "@type": "ImageObject",
  "contentUrl": "http://example.jpg"
}
```

The closest example I have found is [How can I copy a URL from an image's src attribute to an href attribute in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8895358/how-can-i-copy-a-url-from-an-images-src-attribute-to-an-href-attribute-in-jquer). However, I am unsure as to how modify it for the pusposes outlined above.

Comment: No `Microdata` appears at `html`? Is there only one `<img>` within `document`? Are you using `JSON-LD`?

Comment: All the schema data is using JSON-LD. There are several images in the document.

Comment: _"All the schema data is using JSON-LD"_ Not sure what you mean? Why do you want to adjust `JSON-LD` after page load? You would need to parse the text of `<script>` element where `JSON-LD` is present to add the appropriate key, value pairs when `img` is dynamically appended to `document`.

Comment: I guess the simplest solution is to use microdata and do everything inline, correct?

Comment: Have not tried `JSON-LD`. Either approach should yield same result [How to extract/parse HTML using Microdata](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30201345/how-to-extract-parse-html-using-microdata/)

Comment: can we have a demo fiddle of what you've done?

Comment: Sure. Take a look at the microdata example here: https://schema.org/ImageObject#examples This is waht I ended up doing.